# Are equiprobable state same as superposition state

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, hadamard, superposition

How

```python
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
```

helps quantum circuit

```python
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)
```

to put the given qubits in a equiprobable states?

Are equiprobable state and super position state same. Since hadamard gate is used to put quantum states into superposition states.

Also what does (0) and (1) signifies here ? Is it circuit zero and circuit 1?

Comment: Seeing your posting history, I would suggest you to first go over Chapter 2 in Neilsen and Chaung, get an understanding of the mathematical model of qubits and operations on qubits, postulates of quantum mechanics and then start with qiskit.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for such guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superposition states of a qubit are usually of form $$| \psi \rangle = a |0\rangle + b |1\rangle $$

where probabilities of getting state $|0\rangle$ and$ |1\rangle$ after a $Z$-measurement are
$$p(0) = |a|^2$$
$$p(0) = |b|^2$$

Equivprobable states imply that the chances of getting any outcome are the same. i.e., for 1-qubit
$$|a|^2 = |b|^2 = 0.5$$
or
$$ a = b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,\,\, \text{(upto a global phase)}$$

For the code you have given, you are applying Hadamard on both qubits. (0) implies operation on qubit0 and (1) implies operation on qubit1.

The resultant state, say $|\phi\rangle$ would be

$
\begin{align}
|\phi\rangle &= (H \otimes H) |00\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle +|10\rangle+|11\rangle)
\end{align}
$

and thus, resulting in an equiprobable state where the probability of getting any of the four outcomes - $\{|00\rangle , |01\rangle ,|10\rangle,|11\rangle\}$ is equal, and it is $|\frac{1}{2}|^2 = 0.25$

An equviprobable state just means a superposition state with equal probabilities.